# momentjs for checking expired timestamp

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a timestamp coming from a table in utc like: `2018-02-21 23:31:49.391` I'm confident it's UTC time so I make a moment out of it.

```
let exp = moment(2018-02-21 23:31:49.391);
```

That represents an expiration date/time. I'm trying to use moment to check if that timestamp is in the past compared to the current time. I think part of my issue is that perhaps moment doesn't know that's in UTC. If so, how can i specify in the constructor?

To do this comparison/validation I'm creating a new moment like `let now = moment().utc();`

and then comparing the time like

```
now.isAfter(exp)
```

However, it keeps coming back as false for me. Is not specifying the first timestamp as UTC the issue?

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code so we can more easily understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's UTC time, then

```
let exp = moment.utc('2018-02-21 23:31:49.391');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try it:

```
var a = moment('2018-02-21 23:31:49.391');
var b = moment().utc();
var d = a.diff(b,'days');
if (d > 0){
   //a is bigger than b actual moment.
} else if (d < 0){
   //a is smaller than b actual moment.
}else{
   //a =  b
}
```